# match string containing specific substring ending on 4 digits regex

Tags: php, regex, string, pcre

I am trying to match the following type of string:

Match
- 4738
- 3333

No match
- 0447 7474
   9495 - 8485
/2848
/ 9949
- 584888

so i made this regex: `/^(- )?(?=\d{4})$/` but this doesnt match my target string: `- 8549`
this is data i need to analyse:
[image]

I am quite new to regex so all tips and suggestions are welcome on how to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a newline character after each result?

Comment: No there isnt, but made a quick edit to the regex maybe this helps!

Comment: Where is the data you are searching in coming from? Is it like a database record or a file? Because there needs to be a difference in the usecases you are providing: If you want to match - 4738 and not - 0447 7474 or 9495 - 8485 then there must be newline characters in it. Can you show a couple of datasets you have to look in?

Comment: the data comes out of an database. so each example i give will be a separate record. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Allright, lets see what you have :)

Comment: I added an image hopefully to make it a bit more clear what the data is!

Comment: /1863 match or not?

Comment: should not be a match

Comment: @FutureCake, so please define what match? do you want to match only a hyphen then space then four digits?

Comment: yeah you got it

Comment: @FutureCake,Your code didn't work because the end `$`, and the look ahead `:?` will negate each other, make the statement absurd and doesn't match anything. The look ahead must have some space before the end of the statement to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `/^-\s\d{4}$/`, it should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
/^(- )?(\d{4})$/
```

if you don't need to capture any groups:

```
/^(?:- )?\d{4}$/
```